# Data from list not displaying when I select Edit Item

Tags: list, infopath, edit

I created a InfoPath list and published it to my site. I added an InfoPath Form WebPart to Edit Item. Now when I select an entry to edit on my list it does not keep the fields that were populated when it takes me to the edit list. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To showing the data of the item which you have selected need to add some rules. In your edit view add a Form Load rule which will check if the selected item id is not blank then switch to your Edit view and select Id or a unique filed and set a condition that will match the value from list and populated other filed from the same row based on filtering respecting the selected unique field.

here is a details [walk through](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/anneste/2011/11/02/how-to-create-an-infopath-form-to-auto-populate-data-in-sharepoint-2010/) and this [article](https://bernierh.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/customizing-new-edit-and-display-list-forms-using-infopath/) is also helpful. Hope it will help.